# Jsoup returns inconsistent results

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup in order to scrape the following url:

`http://translink.com.au//travel-information/service-notices/25611/details`

I used the following query `#content-left-column > div.content` but the results are inconsistent.

Sometimes I get no results, and sometimes I get the required results.

```
public class JsoupSelectorMain {
public static Elements getAlertsElements(Document document , String query)
{
    return document.select(query);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://translink.com.au//travel-information/service-notices/25611/details").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String str="#content-left-column > div.content";
    Elements element = getAlertsElements(doc, str);

    for(int i=0 ; i<element.size() ; i++){
        System.out.println(element.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("size=" + element.size());
}
```

}

I used `timeout(0)` but it is not the issue. I also checked Jsoup [known issues](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Acomments-desc) but couldn't find similar cases.

What i'm missing here?

Comment: What do you mean you get no results? An exception the document object has no elements, or that the document doesn't include the elements you expect (which basically tells us that the site responded with some other page)?

Comment: If it's the last option, try setting the userAgent. Maybe the site perceives you as a bot (which your program is) and redirects you. By setting a userAgent you mimic a normal web browser/user

Comment: @alkis I get no exceptions, only "empty" results (which is not what i'm expecting to get). I notices that the issue is focused on the string that `document.select(String)` uses. in some cases it works and in some it doensn't. Is the user agent is still relevant in this case?

Comment: Well the thing is what the web site responds with. Since the same code is sometimes produces the results it should and sometimes it doesn't, the problem is with the input. In your case the input is the respond you get from the website. Try printing the document (`System.out.println(doc)`), alongside with the elements. Check if the respond is some kind of error message from the site.

Comment: @alkis this gets really wired. I run (in loop) 50 requests. and I got 2 different results.

Comment: You have to give more information. What do you mean different. What does the wrong content include?

Comment: @alkis both returns HTML page, but some tags, classes and attributes are different.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the site detects it as a mobile user agent and perhaps that's what causing the inconsistency in your results. I created a new project on eclipse and in debug mode I found that the URL was changed to `http://mobile.translink.com.au//travel-information/service-notices/25611/details`

**Here is the screenshot:** 
[image: without assigning .userAgent]

And then I changed this statement:

`doc = Jsoup.connect("http://translink.com.au//travel-information/service-notices/25611/details").timeout(0).get();`

To this:

`doc = Jsoup.connect("http://translink.com.au//travel-information/service-notices/25611/details").timeout(0).userAgent("Chrome").get();`

...So that it can detect it as Non-mobile/Desktop UA.

**After adding the user agent:**
[image]